# Oauth 2.0 WebClient C#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get a token using **Oauth2**, **Webclient** and **C#**, but so far no success.

I am doing it in a console application, once it worked I must take it to an **SSIS script**

```
In this attempt I did it in another way, so it doesn't work for me. I must get the token using WebClient,

I tried the following:

 private static string Token()
        {
            string wClientId = "...";
            string wClientSecretKey = "...";
            string wAccessToken;

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };

            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                HttpRequestMessage tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/token");
                HttpContent httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
                        new[]
                        {
                                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                        });
                tokenRequest.Content = httpContent;
                tokenRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(wClientId + ":" + wClientSecretKey)));
                responseMessage = client.SendAsync(tokenRequest).Result;
            }
            string ResponseJSON = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Please describe what problem you are getting with your current code

Comment: My intention is to do the same as my current code, but using webclient